# Javabuffer returns symbols

Tags: java, byte, buffer, endianness, packet

I would like to read packet payload from dump, but the problem is, that when I calls .toString() it returns a symbols. Using this lib https://github.com/aboutsip/pkts

```
import io.pkts.PacketHandler;
import io.pkts.buffer.Buffer;
import io.pkts.packet.Packet;
import io.pkts.packet.TCPPacket;
import io.pkts.packet.UDPPacket;
import io.pkts.protocol.Protocol;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String t2 = "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/3/xxx/dumpcap.pcap";

        final io.pkts.Pcap pcap = io.pkts.Pcap.openStream(t2);

        pcap.loop(new PacketHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean nextPacket(Packet packet) throws IOException {
                if (packet.hasProtocol(Protocol.TCP)) {
                    TCPPacket tcpPacket = (TCPPacket) packet.getPacket(Protocol.TCP);
                    Buffer buffer = tcpPacket.getPayload();
                    if (buffer != null) {
                        System.out.println("TCP: " + buffer);
                    }
                } else if (packet.hasProtocol(Protocol.UDP)) {

                    UDPPacket udpPacket = (UDPPacket) packet.getPacket(Protocol.UDP);
                    Buffer buffer = udpPacket.getPayload();
                    if (buffer != null) {
                        System.out.println("UDP: " + buffer);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The output is like this:

```
UDP: � Ϥ ̀ml����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
UDP: � ;Ʒ:�� ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
TCP: �Z]����5s��bY���#�O
^A�����/�
UDP: � ϥ � ml����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

Comment: UDP and TCP packages are not text. They might *carry* some text, but they are primarily binary data. If you want to be able to show all UCP/TCP packets in a textual format, then you need to do something like produce a hex dump of the data.

Comment: i am doing it this way, the tutorial result looks readable
https://www.javahelps.com/2017/08/parse-pcap-files-in-java.html

Comment: It looks like the tutorial uses capture files representing plain-text HTTP requests. Whatever you capture is not that. It's either encrypted (HTTPS) or just some binary protocol.

Comment: wow.. i analyzed the file again and you are right, the many of packets were encrypted but the one, which I need to see is decrypted and I can simple use the buffer.toString().contains("XXX") and print it clearly!

thank you very much